# How to start AlarmManager on top of hour?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

How to start AlarmManager on top of the nearest hour? For example when user click on button and time is 12:32, I want to start service at 13:00 and then repeat it each hour, I tried this code, but it doesn't work, it start AlarmManager only a hour later, so if time is 12:32 it starts service at 13:32.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+1);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)myService.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(myService.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(BatteryService.this, 0, i, 0);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*60, pIntent);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create the calendar instance its time is the current time. 12:32 in your example. Then you add one to hour of day. Now its 13:32. You need to set the minutes (and seconds) to 0:

```
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);  // well ...
```

Comment: Providing people with code examples for such simple things deteriortes their ability to learn the apis of classes avilable. Please help people by not giving them a crutch. They should only be given the path, not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try rounding it based on the minutes... Of course this would require getting the **CURRENT** time.

Comment: Could you give me an example how it should look?

Comment: Try looking at the Calendar class and the Math class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
`int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);`
to start you alarm
then use

```
AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR
```

to repeat you alarm
but Notice that the alarm will start now then will be repeated every hour